# How to make C++ program doing 2 things simultaneously?

Tags: c++, time, seconds

Can someone tell me what do I need to do (not to write me code, just tell me) to make C++ doing 2 things simultaneously?

Let's say that I have some timer and some text.
That text moves every 0.5 seconds to the right and times updates every 1 second.

How can I make that ? Don't write me code, as I said, just tell me are there some useful functions. If I am unclear, I will delete this question so it's downovoted (tell me please :). Thank you!

Comment: What OS? You are asking fo OS dependent stuff.

Comment: Windows (10) :)

Comment: WinAPI? Sounds pretty close to what you are asking for if you are developing for windows with c++... also, look into multithreading/parallel processing libraries or just use the standard library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do multiple things at the same time in a C++ program is to use threads.  That a look at `std::thread` for more information.

The point being that the threads run independently of one another and can perform completely separate tasks at the same time.

The advantage of using `std::thread` is that it's portable, so your code is no longer dependent on what operating system you're using.